# ImageIO writes only the background colour but not the graphics

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, javax.imageio

I've got the following statement to write a buffered jPanel image onto a `.png` file. It does write the background colour but not the graphics.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(jPanel.getWidth(), 
jPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
jPanel.paint(g);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("testing.png"));
```

Comment: what do you mean by **graphics**?

Comment: `paintComponent` or maybe `paintImmediate` to circumvent the entire invalidation thing. Also call `g.disposeGraphics()` afterwards

Comment: @Blip Content or shapes (line, oval, etc) drawn on top of the jPanel

Comment: could you post the code where you have drawn the shapes?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues with using `paint` this way, apart from invoking double buffering, which is an unnecessary overhead, it can also cause issues when the component isn't realised on the screen - like not painting things or even triggering a runtime exception.

As a general rule of thumb, don't call `paint`, EVER, instead, use `print` or `printAll`, for example...

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(jPanel.getWidth(), jPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
jPanel.print(g);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("testing.png"));
```

Also, don't forget, you should call `dispose` on `Graphics` which you create to ensure that it releases any underlying resources it might have created.

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal example works for me.
It is better to call `image.createGraphics()` instead of `getGraphics()`.
Make sure to call `super.paintComponent(g)` when you override `paintComponent`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel()
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        }
    };

    jPanel.setSize(120, 120);
    jPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    BufferedImage image =
        new BufferedImage(jPanel.getWidth(), jPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

    jPanel.print(g);

    try
    {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("testing.png"));
        g.dispose();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```